# Multiple HTTP queries on a single connection

Tags: http, connection

Is it possible a Web client to send multiple HTTP queries to a server using only one connection (server IP, server Port, client IP and client Port are the same without "restarting" the connection).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's called [keepalive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keepalive).